# Is it possible to alter an electrical cord for INDOOR Christmas string lights?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am making a modern Christmas tree which will be like a sculpture and want to put LED string candles on different "tiers" of my tree(s). In some areas I'll need to shorten the cord between lights and in other areas I'll need to run a cord with no lights to reach the other levels.

Here is the product I am looking to buy:

[Christmas Candle String Lights, 48Feet 50Pcs LED Candle Lights for Christmas Tree(s](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BGBMN4PH)

Is it possible to cut the wires where needed and use small wire nuts to reconnect them and do the same with extending the cord where I'd like it to run without any lights? Or will I destroy them? I don't want to get battery operated candles since I'll need about sixty lights per tree (I'm making two identical 10ft tall trees). Battery operated  flickering candles would give me the most flexibility in terms of physical placement but I'll be spending so much time charging 120 batteries when they run down.

Also, wanted to say that I edited my post to make it clear that these lights will be for indoor use only.

Comment: Note you *can* get xmas lights that contain their own Li-Ion battery & charge from USB. I have some where a 1hr charge will last a week. Couldn't tell you who made them or where they came from now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible; but wirenuts are not the answer if these are going outdoors. These are IP44 rated, meaning they're not fully weatherproof; the indication is "light showers" so depending on your climate, these could fail quickly.

I recommend heatshrink solder-seal butt splices for (permanent) outdoor low-voltage wiring. You may be able to get that to work with custom splices of these lights. Note that modifying these lights voids their UL approval and puts you into custom-DIY territory.

In this case though, I'd look for another product that is more weather-tolerant, and if your needs include custom wiring lengths and distances you'd be better off with battery-powered candles and custom wire lengths connected to a power supply in a waterproof project box. There are many guides online for how Christmas lights hobbyists like myself build ornaments and displays out of lights.

Comment: I forgot to mention that these will be only for indoor use. I'll never put these outdoors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the battery powered lights, just power them with a wall wart (plug power supply) of the correct voltage. I did some several years ago but I purchased some small buck (about the size as a postage stamp pined out as a 78xx chip) converters and placed one in each battery box and powered several with one plug supply,just had to make the cord to connect them. I think they came from china and were about $0.30 each. These will protect the others if one fails it will shut down until the fault is fixed.

Much safer and the light is stable. The voltage can be adjusted for the number of LEDs. This also keeps the wire size to a much more workable size. If a wire nut comes off and shorts it should not arc or start a fire.

Comment: Your idea sounds interesting but wouldn't wiring each battery operated light be just as much work if not more than using the electrical lights?

Answer (score 0):

The key thing is **LED**.

In the old days, you would have a bunch of tiny incandescent bulbs. Since they used so much power, they needed to be plugged in. And the nature of incandescent bulbs is such that using 120V AC power is just as good as using low-voltage DC power, so sticking with 120V AC to keep things *simple* made a lot of sense. That being said, it raised plenty of safety issues because (a) you had 120V AC power all over the place and (b) even the little bulbs would run hot, and (c) if used outside there could be all kinds of problems (I know this particular installation won't be outside, but it is worth mentioning)

However, LED technology is entirely different. LEDs are, by their nature, low-voltage DC devices. The technology has improved and mass-production reached the level where it is possible to make tiny low-output LEDs that each include their own *driver* circuit to convert from high-voltage AC to low-voltage DC at an affordable price. But many of the safety issues still remain because you still have 120V running between the LED/driver sections.

The better solution is to use low-voltage LEDs and a matching power supply. This is *not* the same as "battery powered". Yes, they could be battery powered, but you could also hook up a Tesla PowerWall and battery-power your entire house. Rather, this is converting high voltage to low voltage and then using that *relatively safe* low voltage to power the LEDs. So you get the safety of low voltage together with the unlimited runtime/capacity of 120V AC power - the best of both worlds.

There is also a *huge* concern with electrical products sourced from Amazon and other online resellers that they are often not UL or ETL-listed. Not being UL or ETL-listed is *not* a guarantee of a problem. But given the nature of the intended use of the product (running thin wires with 120V AC power through the tangled mess of a tree...), not having that listing - a real assurance of quality - is something to be concerned about. However, if you use a quality power supply (ideally UL or ETL listed) to convert from 120V AC to low voltage DC, *most* of the concerns disappear. You can then more reasonably use "whatever" stuff from Amazon, eBay, Alibaba, etc. **and make your own modifications too**, with relatively little concern for safety. You can't be zapped by 120V from a frayed wire or loose connection in the tree if 120V isn't in the tree at all. And the total power that can come pouring out in a shorting, arcing connection will be limited by the power supply rather than by your circuit breaker. (120V @ 20A will burn up a tree pretty quickly.)

Comment: That was a ton of info. But I'm unclear as to what you're suggesting I do specifically in my case. The lights I linked in my question are LED and claim they are UL listed. Are you saying I might not be able to trust the description because it's amazon?

Comment: I just double-checked and you are correct that they are UL listed. That is, to some extent, the exception when it comes to Amazon products not "Sold by Amazon" (i.e. they are sold by someone else and pass through the Amazon warehouse but since they are not "Sold by Amazon", Amazon is not the *legal* middle-man and therefore does not have to guarantee being fit for sale in the US - a lot of companies from Asia use that as a way to sell non-UL/ETL electrical stuff in the US). Assuming it is correct, that is very good news.

Comment: **However**, I still recommend using low-voltage stuff and a plug-in power supply. If you are using 12V or 24V DC the danger if you cut a wire and don't splice it right or a wire comes loose, etc. is a tiny, tiny fraction of what it is with 120V AC. With 120V AC, a small problem combined with wet finger (e.g., spilled drink) can be very quickly *fatal*, because it takes very little current to kill with 120V AC. And since these are LEDs anyway, low voltage DC will work just fine as long as the products are designed to work that way, unlike the old incandescent bulbs.

Answer (score 0):

The picture shows a power supply, so the LEDs are not powered directly by mains:

[image]

If you do not intend to change the number of LEDs, then you should be able to extend the wires. Make sure to check the voltage on the power supply, if it is low enough to be safe then there's no problem. Also check the output is insulated from mains. The text on amazon mentions 30V which is a bit high for low voltage, but not deadly, so this should be okay.

Like Fredric I recommend heatshrink solder-seal [butt splices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unxEdyW8RP8), or the crimp variant, or for indoor use just solder the wires and add some heat shrink on top.

If the power supply outputs a low voltage (<12V) then the LED bulbs are probably wired in parallel, each bulb contains a current limiting resistor, and you will be able to cut wires and rewire them as you need.

If it outputs a high voltage (in this case 30V or more) then they may be wired in series instead. In this case the bulbs do not contain a current limiting resistor and current is controlled by the supply, which expects to drive a certain number of LEDs in series. If you remove some LEDs, the supply will output the same current, at a lower voltage. These supplies usually have an allowed output voltage range outside of which they will not work, so if you remove some bulbs it is not possible to know beforehand if it will work.